# create linear function with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I make linear function in javascript like if you search on google:
y=2x+7

I tried using google charts but it didnt work...
here is the code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCurveTypes);
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var h = window.prompt('enter a number');

function drawCurveTypes() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'linear');
  data.addRows([
  ]);

  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    addRows('[x,y]');
    x = x + h;
    y++;
  }

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    series: {
      1: {
        curveType: 'function'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `addRows('[x,y]')` is .. wrong. Do you really want to add a *string* '[x,y]'? Plus, the `addRows` method does not exist and will throw an error. You probably want to create an initial array and populate it with the actual `x` and `y` values, and then pass that to `data.addRows`.

Comment: can you give me code example?